# how to replace ' with another special character using str_replace php

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a function that receives a post title and cut it when the post title is longer than 40 character. The function works very well except when the string has `'` in it.

This is how the browser display the title in the original page (before the 'cut')

```
dall'high-tech all'high-car, bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
```

When the string is passed to the function and the function cut it at the 40-th character the string returned is very short:

```
dall'high-tech
```

I am using `substr()` to cut it after the 40-th character:

```
substr($my_string, 0, 40);
```

I think the problem has to do with the ' character in the string. I have tried to replace the `'` character with `chr(134)` using

```
str_replace("'", chr(134), $my_string);
```

But `str_replace()` fails to replace `'` with `†`. (I tried also using `\'` and `chr(39)` instead of `'` and also using `B` instead of `chr(134)`).

So, now I don't know what to do. I have spent already 5 hours trying to fix this problem. I am sure someone has gone through it before and might help me.

Thank you

Comment: Please check: http://codepad.org/EU4e1q89

Comment: Are these Unicode characters? Are you sure `'` is actually `'` and not any other similar Unicode character?

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this before you do the substr():

```
$my_string = html_entity_decode($my_string, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Another option to try is using [mb_substr()](http://php.net/mb-substr) which performs a multi-byte safe substr() operation based on number of characters.

Comment: what does it have to do with substr?

Comment: For some people (as I discovered while googling) this is a solution. It probably has to do with their character set. Honestly, I wasn't able to reproduce the behavior with PHP 5.2.11 -> http://ideone.com/qixOP

Comment: @Shiplu OP tried to use substr, but it may indeed fail on a multi-byte strings, leaving you with only one byte of a multi-byte character at the end of the string.

Comment: your latest addition in the answer (`mb_substr`) makes sense now.

Comment: @GolezTrol I commented before cillosis added `mb_substr` part.

Comment: $my_string=str_replace(chr(39), "B", $my_string);
    if (str_word_count($my_string)>0) {
    $cut_at = strrpos(substr($my_string, 0, $cut_at), ' ');
    }
  
    $my_string = html_entity_decode($my_string, ENT_QUOTES);
    $my_string_output = mb_substr($my_string, 0, $cut_at);